# Inconsistent results when passing array to ActiveRecord#where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 4.2.7.1, Ruby 2.3.1 and MySQL as my DB. I have a background job that is responsible for collecting analytics about the database which performs some very costly read operations. One of them in particular is behaving inconsistently and it seems to be caused by inconsistent behaviour of the IN clause in the SQL query.

The rails calls look something like this:

```
MyModel.some_scope.where(id: OtherModel.where(<CONDITION>).group(:my_model_id).select(:my_model_id)).count
```

Which boils down to an `IN` clause in the resulting SQL query. This works fine in general, but when the nested query (`OtherModel...`) gets large (~2000 results) I start to see inconsistent results from the `IN`. When running the query over and over again the values I see drift up and down independently of actual changes to the database.

If I re-write the query above to use joins, like so:

```
MyModel.some_scope.joins(:other_model).where(<CONDITION>).select(:id).uniq.count
```

I see a consistent result from the query every time. I have no problem re-writing the query in this case and, therefore, have a solution to my problem, but I'd really like to understand what's going on in MySQL to cause the strange behaviour.

It's worth noting that the working query (with the join) returns ~1300 records, while the broken query is in the ~1400-1600 range.

Comment: try something like `MyModel.joins(:other_model).some_scope.count` and see if that works. `IN` statements are really heavy, and more if you're including more than 2000 possible values. UPDATE: I didn't see that group by. You could also add it to the query `MyModel.joins(:other_model).some_scope.group(:my_model_id).count`, or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in the question, the join approach is consistent. The workaround works fine, but I'm hoping to understand why the IN approach is inconsistent. Slow I would understand (and expect), but the inconsistency surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. The join is behaving exactly the same as the subquery. When I tested the join approach, I happened to hit a stable period. I'm now able to reproduce the inconsistencies with either approach.

The issue is that the data is legitimately changing fast enough that I'm seeing the results fluctuate wildly. It stems from a bug in the `<CONDITION>`.